# Behavior of static methods/variables change after adding instance variable in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, static-methods, static-members, abstraction

This isn't so much of a problem as it is a question. I have several classes that inherit the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class PixelEditorWindow {
    protected static int windowHeight, windowWidth;

    public PixelEditorWindow() {
        setWindowSize();
    }

    protected abstract void setWindowSize();

    public static int getWindowWidth() {
        return windowWidth;
    }

    public static int getWindowHeight() {
        return windowHeight;
    }
}
```

I have each class inherit the abstract method setWindowSize, where they set what their window size will be, and these two variables are set, as follows:

```
protected void setWindowSize() {
    windowWidth = 400;
    windowHeight = 400;
}
```

That works perfectly. But I also need all of them to keep track of the JFrame they're contained in now, so I modified this class in the following way:

```
public abstract class PixelEditorWindow {
    protected int windowHeight, windowWidth;
    JFrame frame;

    public PixelEditorWindow(JFrame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
        setWindowSize();
    }

    public JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }

    protected abstract void setWindowSize();

    public int getWindowWidth() {
        return windowWidth;
    }

    public int getWindowHeight() {
        return windowHeight;
    }
}
```

Now, all inherited classes have the same window size, which is whatever type of window was instantiated last. <strike>I can fix it by having another class that inherits this one that all the sub-classes inherit, but that's messier than I'd like.</strike> EDIT: just realized I can't do that either, but there are lots of other messy ways to work around this. Why is it that adding a non-static instance variable mucks everything up? Or a better question I suppose - why is it that not having a non-static instance variable allows this to work?

Comment: Please show the implementations of `setWindowSize` so that we can see how they interact with the parent class fields.

Comment: The variables should never have been static in the first place. You're on the right track, just keep going.

Answer (score 0):

"static" means association at the class level.

Non-static means association at object level.

Basically, I would need to remove all static stuff. And later on use "static" when you know why you need it.